# Make the change of "active" class in the menu more reliable when scrolling

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, wordpress, wordpress-theming

### My issue

I have implemented the code to change "active" class of menu when page scrolling.

Here is the code I use to manage this behavior (extract from main.js file) :

```
$("a.nav-link").click(function(e){
    $('html, body').animate({
        scrollTop: $(e.target.hash).offset().top - 15
    });  
    $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass('active');
    var $parent = $(this).parent();
    $parent.addClass('active');
});

window.addEventListener('load', () => {
    const headings = document.querySelectorAll('section');
    var topMenu = $(".navbar-nav"),
    topMenuHeight = topMenu.outerHeight()+15,
    menuItems = topMenu.find("a");

    document.addEventListener('scroll', (e) => {
        headings.forEach(ha => {
            const rect = ha.getBoundingClientRect();
            if(rect.top > 0 && rect.top < 150) {    
                if(ha.id != "presentation")
                {
                    const location = window.location.toString().split('#')[0];
                    history.replaceState(null, null, location + '#' + ha.id);
                    //console.log(menuItems.filter("[href='/ea-jamm/#"+ha.id+"']").parent()[0].classList);
                    if(menuItems.filter("[href='/ea-jamm/#"+ha.id+"']").parent()[0].classList.contains("active")){
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        menuItems
                        .parent().removeClass("active")
                        .end().filter("[href='/ea-jamm/#"+ha.id+"']").parent().addClass("active");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    menuItems
                    .parent().removeClass("active")
                    const location = window.location.toString().split('#')[0];
                    history.replaceState(null, null, location);
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
```

You can constat the behavior here : http://mehdigallois.fr/ea-jamm/

However, when i scroll the page very quickly, the change of "active" class in the menu is not reliable and sometimes the first menu item is active while the page is at bottom. (in this case, it is the last menu item h
which has to be "active")

**How can I make the change of "active" class in the menu more reliable when scrolling quickly ?**

(Moreover, when I scroll the page completely at bottom on tablet device (1024 x 1366), the last menu item "Nous contacter" does not have the "active" class : it still the second to last which has the "active" class. Same when i click on the last menu item. (Check the behavior for yourselves.))

### Track(s) / Solution(s)

This issue is linked to this another question about "asynchronous panning": ["This site appears to use a scroll-linked positioning effect. This may not work well with asynchronous panning"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37098306/this-site-appears-to-use-a-scroll-linked-positioning-effect-this-may-not-work)

I can try to:

- implement **debouncing** aka update the class when the scrolling stops, not while it's occuring

OR

- implement **throttle**, so it only updates every n milliseconds, not every scroll event

Comment: Where is code that you share above in the site you linked?

Comment: @oguzhancerit In the site I linked, the code is in main.js 
Here is the path to find this file : ea-jamm > wp-content > themes/ea-jamm-theme > assets > js > main.js

Comment: can you move it to index end of the footer to manipulate it on the live site?

Comment: @oguzhancerit i moved it, can you check if it is ok for you ?

Comment: great! I'm trying something

Comment: can you remove code snippet from the site

Comment: I didn't accomplish beacuse of the environment but I strongly recomment research here; https://www.sitepoint.com/throttle-scroll-events/ this will be helpful for your problem.

Comment: @oguzhancerit ok, thank you! Do you still need I remove the code snippet?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/226323/discussion-between-oguzhancerit-and-medmatrix).